# Android download manager not working for me

Tags: android

Hi everyone i am a bit stuck with **DownloadManager** trying to add a download functionality to my sample app.
the problem is that when i execute the code to download a file nothing happen and after about 15 min a notification show up ( unsuccessful download ).

here is the code i used :

```
downloadManager  = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4");
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
request.setTitle("Sample video name.mp4");
Long reference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you ask for Storage write permission ?

Comment: Yes i did and it's granted

Comment: did you setup fileprovider?

Comment: No as i don't know what is that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this function to download the file using the Download manager:

```
private long downloadFile(Uri uri, String fileStorageDestinationUri, String fileName) {

    long downloadReference = 0;

    downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    try {
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);

        //Setting title of request
        request.setTitle(fileName);

        //Setting description of request
        request.setDescription("Your file is downloading");

        //set notification when download completed
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

        //Set the local destination for the downloaded file to a path within the application's external files directory
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(fileStorageDestinationUri, fileName);

        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();

        //Enqueue download and save the referenceId
        downloadReference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        BaseUtils.showToast(mContext, "Download link is broken or not availale for download");
        Log.e(TAG, "Line no: 455,Method: downloadFile: Download link is broken");

    }
    return downloadReference;
}
```

Now call this method like below:

```
long downloadFileRef = downloadFile(Uri.parse("http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4"), "/YourAppName/", "fileName.mp4");
if (downloadFileRef != 0) {
    BaseUtils.showToast(mContext, "Starting download...");
}else {
    BaseUtils.showToast(mContext, "File is not available for download");
}
```

You can find the downloaded file in `Storage/YourAppName/fileName.mp4` in your device

Comment: it actually works on my android studio emulator but not on my physical device. any ideas why ?

Comment: What error do you get in a physical device? show the error log

Comment: nothing shows but after like 15 min notification shows ( download unsuccessful )

Comment: looks like it's about android version the emulator that the code works on is android 7 and my device which the code does not work on is android 8.1 to confirm that i installed new emu with android 8.1 and yeah it's not working

Comment: Hey i see the problem it was vpn app that was making the problem. your code works super.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how i implement it:

```
public void downloadHD(){
    long downloadFileRef = downloadFile(Uri.parse(Video.VideoUrl()), "/"+getString(R.string.app_name)+"/", Video.VideoName()+" HD"+".mp4");
    if (downloadFileRef != 0) {
        this.showToast(getString(R.string.startdownload));
    }else {
        this.showToast(getString(R.string.notavialblefordownload));
    }
}
```

then :

```
private long downloadFile(Uri uri, String fileStorageDestinationUri, String fileName) {

        long downloadReference = 0;

        downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        try {
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);

            //Setting title of request
            request.setTitle(fileName);

            //Setting description of request
            request.setDescription(getString(R.string.downloadingnow));

            //set notification when download completed
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

            //Set the local destination for the downloaded file to a path within the application's external files directory
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(fileStorageDestinationUri, fileName);

            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();

            //Enqueue download and save the referenceId
            downloadReference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
           this.showToast(getString(R.string.downloadnotavilablenow));


        }
        return downloadReference;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you must specify the destination path , cookies header.

```
   private fun downloadByDownloadManager
   (url: String,userAgent: String,
    contentDisposition: String) {
    val mimeType = "application/pdf"
    val filename = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType)
    val request: DownloadManager.Request = DownloadManager.Request(
        Uri.parse(url))
    request.setMimeType(mimeType)
    val cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url)
    request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies)
    request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", okhttp3.internal.userAgent)
    request.setDescription("Downloading File...")
    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI or DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
    request.setAllowedOverRoaming(true)
    request.setAllowedOverMetered(true)
    request.setTitle(filename)
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner()
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS, "/Annotation/"+filename)
    val downloader : DownloadManager = getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
    val downloadFileRef = downloader.enqueue(request)
    if (downloadFileRef != 0L) {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Downloading File...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Something went wrong.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }

}
```